# How do I call the getInputHtml() method of a custom fieldtype plugin from another plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

**Plugin 1**

I have a plugin that is a custom fieldtype.  It works fine, and has a getInputHtml() method that behaves as expected.

**Plugin 2**

Now, I have a second plugin, where I want to output the HTML from the Plugin 1 getInputHtml() method.

I have the FieldModel:

```
$field = $field->getField();
```

I have the Plugin 1 fieldtype object

```
$fieldtype = craft()->fields->populateFieldType($field, $element);
```

And I call the getInputHtml() method:

```
$fieldtype->getInputHtml($field->handle, $value);
```

If I place the necessary files at the base of Plugin 2 `plugin2/templates/plugin1/_field/input` everything works fine.  But I can't seem to access the input HTML template in the context of Plugin 1: `plugin1/templates/_field/input`

I've tried to update the Template Path in various ways before calling $fieldtype->getInputHtml():

```
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath(craft()->path->getPluginsPath());
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath(craft()->path->getPluginsPath() . 'plugin1/');
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath(craft()->path->getCpTemplatesPath());
```

Everything I have tried has resulted in a template error:

```
Unable to find the template "plugin1/_field/input".
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the call to Plugin 2 happening in a CP or action request?

Comment: The call from Plugin 2 to Plugin 1 is happening on the front-end (a variable passes of the call to the service layer).  At this point, this is a largely academic pursuit about paths.  This is really not a good idea because getInputHtml() is designed to work on the CP side only and comes (potentially) with a lot of extra baggage for anything involving the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that the call is happening on the front-end. Because of this, the template renderer is not looking for the template at `plugin1/templates/_field/input` as it normally would, but at `plugin1/_field/input`, which explains the error message.

If Plugin 1 is your own plugin then you should be able to include the `templates` part of the path in the render call, for example:

```
return craft()->templates->render('templates/_field/input');
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

Alternatively, and I would recommend this, since this is a front-end call, you could create your own function `getFrontEndInputHtml()` to return the html appropriately.

Comment: My initial goal was to be able to target any plugin this way but I think your answer sums up what is possible here.  I can modify Plugin 1's render path or add an additional function to get the results I want for that plugin but that doesn't help me address any plugin I don't have control over.  For Field Types in other plugins, it appears I'll need to explore alternative routes to communicate with them or use the template data they use.